# Validate input and display text accordingly javascript

Tags: javascript, input, text

I am working on my assignment where I have to ask a user to type specific letter (capital), if not then I am not supposed to process the input data

Tried to use if and specified which letters I am expecting

```js
function myFunction() {
  var bokstav, r4;
  bokstav = document.getElementById("tipping").value;
  if (bokstav !== "H" || bokstav !== "U" || bokstav !== "B") {
    r4 = "Du har ikke brukt stort bokstav eller tastet ugyldig tegn";
  } else if (bokstav = "H") {
    r4 = "Hjemme";
  } else if (bokstav = "U") {
    r4 = "Uavgjort";
  } else {
    r4 = "Borte";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = r4;
}
```

```html
<p>Type H/B/U:</p>

<input id="tipping" value="H" type="text" />

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

I expect the user to type just H, U or B. Then if the "H" is typed then "Hjemme" is displayed on the screen, if "B" is typed then to show "Borte" on the screen and so on. Otherwise ask the user to type only H, U, B ( capital)

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code yourself using `debugger;` in your browser?

Comment: I don´t know how to do that...

Comment: @Dimarco - You have to use `&&` operator instead of `||` here. And  in `if/else` use `===` for comparision instead of `=`. This will fix the issue.

Comment: I have just tried and it didn´t work:   var b,r4;
  b= document.getElementById("tipping").value);
 if (b!==="H"&&b!==="U"&& b!==="B") {
   r4="Du har ikke brukt stort bokstav eller tastet ugyldig tegn";
 } else if (b==="H"){
   r4="Hjemme";
 } else if (b==="U"){
   r4="Uavgjort";
 } else {
   r4="Borte";
 }
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = r4;
}

Comment: @Dimarco - `===` is used for strict equality and `!==` for strict inequality (not `!===`).